# Some parameters missed in Request.QueryString("returnURL")

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, webforms, query-string

In my project (ASP.NET Webform), I have a hyperlink on a view. When I click on this link, it will direct me to another view on my website. Here is the link on my view.

```
<a href="https://mytest.com/mysite/mypage.aspx?returnURL=https://mytest.com/mysite/DynamicView.aspx?view_code=_SAA1DKIVJ&amp;module_code=R&amp;selected_row=0258B963A2">View My Ticket</a>
```

Now, I click the above link, and I catch the request at the Application_BeginRequest event in the Global.asax page. Please note the different values between Request.QueryString and Request.QueryString("returnURL").

Request.QueryString    `returnURL=https%3a%2f%2fmytest.com%2fmysite%2fDynamicView.aspx%3fview_code%3d_SAA1DKIVJ&module_code=R&selected_row=0258B963A2`

Request.QueryString("returnURL")

`https://mytest.com/mysite/DynamicView.aspx?view_code=_SAA1DKIVJ`

As you can see, Request.QueryString("returnURL") is missing two parameters `module_code` and `selected_row`

I have no idea why this weird thing occurs. I am expecting Request.QueryString("returnURL") should have the same value as Request.QueryString.

I would appreciate your help in this matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the parameters properly. There are two `?` in the url, that is not allowed.

```
<a href="https://mytest.com/mysite/mypage.aspx?returnURL=<%= 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://mytest.com/mysite/DynamicView.aspx?view_code=_SAA1DKIVJ&module_code=R&selected_row=0258B963A2") 
 %>">View My Ticket</a>
```

Comment: Good catch, @VDWWD. Thanks so much!